# Flag to skip flyway migration sequence

Tags: spring, database-migration, flyway

Do we have a way to skip flyway migration based on spring profile or flag read from properties files . Like the skip property given below . The skip property is not there so it will throw exception but I think you get an idea by looking at the bean configuration . How do we achieve this with existing flyway version 3.2.1 in spring

```
<bean id="flyway-integ" class="org.flywaydb.core.Flyway" init-method="migrate" depends-on="dataSource">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="initOnMigrate" value="true" />
        <property name="validateOnMigrate" value="false" />
        <property name="locations" value="migration/prod" />
        <property name="skip" value="${dev.mode}" />
</bean>
```

Comment: I think another way is to write a wrapper bean around flyway and call bean init method based on  the skip property in the wrapper bean for flyway .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that using the spring annotation `@ConditionalOnProperty` and setting `flyway.enabled=false` in your Spring profile's config list where you want it to disable.

```
@ConditionalOnBean(DataSource.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "flyway", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
@Bean(initMethod = "migrate")
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "flyway")
public Flyway flyway() {
    Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
```

Comment: this seems to be Spring Boot's annotation, not Spring one